Transform a text with unicode numbers into the actual characters
In my UTF-8 text Perl script file, I have the following text (obtained by opening and reading another txt document):
$str = "F'252'r ('8364')"

Numbers in between the ' quotes are unicodes in decimal. For the above example, ü and € respectively.
What is the code required to produce a string so that the editor displays it as: "Für (€)"
I have tried using Encode::encode, Encode::decode, pack and unpack.

Have you tried the chr() built-in? perl -CSA -E 'say chr 252' prints ü, and similar for 8364.

Ok, that's for a single character, for a string?

I can't believe this isn't a duplicate.

@tripleee I found some questions about converting HTML entities to characters, but not other formats like the one in this question when I looked. I'm a tad surprised too.

Using chr and a regular expression to find the numbers in quotes:
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use open qw/:std :encoding(UTF-8)/; # Tell perl standard output etc. use utf-8

my $str = "F'252'r ('8364')";
print "$str --> ";
$str =~ s/'(\d+)'/chr $1/eg; # e treats the replacement as code, not text
say $str;

Example usage:
$ perl demo.pl
F'252'r ('8364') --> Für (€)


Working, thank you ever so much.

Depending on the expected input, you might want s/'([0-9]+)'/chr $1/eg instead of s/'(\d+)'/chr $1/eg. The difference is that \d matches any Unicode digit (e.g. "\N{DEVANAGARI DIGIT TWO}"), but chr $1 will get indigestion if $1 contains anything other than ASCII digits. If your Perl is at least 5.14 you can get the same effect with s/'(\d+)'/chr $1/ega. The /a modifier restricts character classes like \w and \d to ASCII, but is not available until Perl 5.13.10.

@Shawn use open qw/:std :encoding(????)/; What to use for latin1/cp 1252/iso-8859-1?

@AlexNet iso-8859-1 and latin1 should work as encoding names according to https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode::Supported

ISO-8859-1 doesn't have the euro sign though. You'd need -15 for that.
